# Missing first result after fetching from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**This is my code:**

```
$q4 = "Select * from namebook LIMIT 0, 10 ";
$r4 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q4);
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

**and I'm fetching them like this**

```
<div id="namelistdiv"><table>
    <?php while ($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo "<a href=contacts2.php?id=" . $row4['ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ1'] . ">" . $row4['ΟΝΟΜΑ'] . '&nbsp&nbsp' . $row4['ΕΠΙΘΕΤΟ'] . '</a>' ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table> </div>
```

but for some reason I miss my first result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` unnecessarily after your query is run and before your loop. This fetches, but never uses, the first row. Thus is not not available to you in your loop.

```
$q4 = "Select * from namebook LIMIT 0, 10 ";
$r4 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q4);
$row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($r4, MYSQLI_ASSOC); // <-- REMOVE THIS
```

Comment: Thanks so much . i should had figure out that but i didn't :/